# Como impedir copiar os estilos e o drag 'n drop no Summernote?

Tags: javascript, summernote

Quando copio alguma coisa para dentro do Summernote, vai tudo o que estava na origem da cópia (imagens, estilos e etc). Tem alguma forma de impedir isso?

Comment: Já procuraste se esse editor têm eventos para poderes processar o `paste` ou configuração para que tipo de `paste` ou conteúdo permite?

Comment: O paste eu achei, mas o drag and drop não. Consegui achar um script que passa retira os estilos do texto do clipboard e cola como plain text, mas quando faço o drag and drop, ele faz os dois. Cola o texto desformatado e o texto com estilos.